# How to send post request with text in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Api with Post method which searchs keywords in DataBase. I want to make search form in Angular. I tried this code,but nothing works. How should i send text in angular correct? I have an error wright now `Http failure response for https://localhost:44359/search/: 404 Not Found`

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="text" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="search()"  
>Submit</button>
```

Typscript

```
export class TextSlidesComponent {
public text: string;
Url: string = "";
public SlidesFinded : any [] ;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

this.Url = baseUrl;
}  
search(text) {
 this.http.post(this.Url + 'search/', this.text).subscribe(result => 
console.log(result));
}
}
```

C# Api

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("/search/{searchform}")]
    public ActionResult Search(string searchform)
    {
     var search = _context.SlideDB.Where(p => p.TextSlide.Contains(searchform));

        return Ok(search);
    }
```

Comment: You are not binding the input field to the text attribute on the template, you should add the ngModel attribute: 
`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="text" >`

Comment: @MehdiBenmoda after adding ngModel I have context error in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call subscribe() inside your component, otherwise request wont get invoked

```
search() {
    this.http.post(this.Url + '/search/', this.text).subscribe((data)=>{
        return data;
    })
```

;
    }

also use ngModel to bind the input text

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: Where's the ngModel binding ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Is my post method in Angular written correctly?I have error to failure response

Comment: @Sajeetharan  with adding ngModel i have context error in html

Comment: @Sajeetharan  "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions."

Comment: @Sajeetharan and this post dont work correctly too.  I have only ' "https://localhost://search/' and no text

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: @Sajeetharan  sorry for my English, I have Route on C# "/search/{searchform}" and angular dont send "text" only /search/

Comment: When using ngModel you need to put the name attribute too. Use this: 
`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="text">`

Comment: @ MehdiBenmoha after of all changes request doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe your post call.

`this.http.post(this.Url + '/search/', text).subscribe(result => console.log(result));`